# xlwings Python error in specifying Inputs into Classes

Tags: excel, python-3.x, class, xlwings, vba

I am trying to input data (spot rates, and maturity) from Excel into python code using the xlwing module.

In my python file (pythonLearn.py), I have the following lines

```
import os
import numbers
import xlwings as xw
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import YieldCurve as yc


@xw.func
def py_Rate(T, spot_rate):
    yc.add_spot_rate(T, spot_rate)
```

In my class module file (YieldCurve.py), I have the following code

```
import math

class ForwardRates(object): # create a bootstrap yieldcurve

    def __init__(self):
        self.forward_rates = []
        self.spot_rates = dict()

    def add_spot_rate(self, T, spot_rate):
        self.spot_rates[T] = spot_rate

    def __calculate_forward_rate___(self, T1, T2):
        R1 = self.spot_rates[T1]
        R2 = self.spot_rates[T2]
        forward_rate = (R2*T2 - R1*T1)/(T2 - T1)
        return forward_rate

    def get_forward_rates(self):
        periods = sorted(self.spot_rates.keys())
        for T2, T1 in zip(periods, periods[1:]):
            forward_rate = self.__calculate_forward_rate___(T1, T2)
            self.forward_rates.append(forward_rate)
        return self.forward_rates
```

When I try to add spot rates with the command (in Excel), '= py_Rate(1.0, 10.5); I get the following error

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_spot_rate'    fr.add_spot_rate(T, spot_rate)  File "c:\users\admin\documents\pythonlearning\pythonLearningExcel5.py", line 155, in py_Rate    ret = func(*args)  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-ckages\xlwings\udfs.py", ine 250, in call_udf    res = call_udf(script, fname, args, this_workbook, FromVariant(caller))  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlwings\server.py", line 190, in CallUDF    return func(*args)  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py", line 586, in *invokeex*    return S_OK, -1, self.*invokeex*(dispid, lcid, wFlags, args, None, None)  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py", line 283, in *invoke*    return self.*invoke*(dispid, lcid, wFlags, args)  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py", line 278, in *Invoke*

Any xlwings/python (3.4 is my version, by-the-way) who can help?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Found out from experts, I submit the worked solution here.
Apparently, one can't use a class method directly, you'd need to do something like this:

```
import xlwings as xw
import numpy as np
import yieldCurve as fr

@xw.func
def py_Rate(T, spotRate):
    fwd_rate = fr.ForwardRates()
    fwd_rate.add_spot_rate(T, spotRate)
```